# Probability recursion on normal distribution

Tags: probability-theory

I'm currently reading [this paper](http://www.datascienceassn.org/sites/default/files/Black-Litterman%20Model%20In%20Detail.pdf). I have one question on some probability part.
In the paper they have the following equations.
$$ P(A)\sim \mathcal {N}(\Pi,\tau \Sigma), r_A \sim \mathcal{N}(P(A),\Sigma) \tag{11}\label{11}$$
$$ r_A \sim \mathcal{N}(\Pi,(1+\tau)\Sigma)  \tag{12}\label{12}$$
My question is that I have absolutely no idea how they pass from $\eqref{11}$ to $\eqref{12}$. It is of course some lack in probability theory for something like recursive functions maybe?. I don't know. Can somebody explain this relationship? Why $\mathcal{N}(\mathcal {N}(\Pi,\tau \Sigma),\Sigma)$ equals $\mathcal{N}(\Pi,(1+\tau)\Sigma)$? (if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: are you sure the equation indexes are correct?

Comment: Sorry, the indexes are correct, it was the paper that was not, it was an old version. I updated the link to a newer revision of the paper which is the one I'm reading.

Comment: In effect you are asking why, with $X_1 \sim \mathcal N(X_0,\Sigma_1)$ where $X_0 \sim \mathcal N(\Pi,\Sigma_0)$, this gives $X_1 \sim \mathcal N(\Pi,\Sigma_0+\Sigma_1)$.  The mean and varaince can be checked with the laws of total expectation and total variance.

Comment: I see @Henry . Do you have any good reference? I only find references and videos related to ${\displaystyle \operatorname {E} (X)=\sum _{i}{\operatorname {E} (X\mid A_{i})\operatorname {P} (A_{i})}.}$ and no so much in continuous functions. Thanks!

Comment: You have two answers.  Leander Tilsted Kristensen's is the equivalent of me saying $X_1-X_0$ is independent of $X_0$, so $X_1$ is the sum of two independent random variables with normal distributions.  You will find plenty of references for that in introductory probability and statistics books

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the context of $r_A \sim \mathcal{N}(P(A),\Sigma)$, should be interpreted as the conditional distribution of $r_A$ given $P(A)$ and $r_A \sim \mathcal{N}(\Pi , (1+\tau)\Sigma))$ is then the marginal distribution $r_A$.

We can derive the relation in the following way. If $r_A | P(A) \sim \mathcal{N}(P(A),\Sigma)$, then $$(r_A - P(A))|P(A) \sim N(0,\Sigma),$$
but since this conditional distribution does not depend on $P(A)$ we may in fact conclude that $r_A - P(A)$ and $P(A)$ are independent random variables/vectors. Writing $r_A$ as
$$r_A = (r_A - P(A)) + P(A)$$
we may conclude, that $r_A$ is the sum of two independent variables/vectors with distributions $\mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$ and $\mathcal{N}(\Pi,\tau\Sigma)$ respectively, and thus conclude that
$$r_A \sim \mathcal{N}(\Pi , (1+\tau)\Sigma).$$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
f(x|\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\theta}{\sigma}\right)^2}
$$
Conjugating the prior distribution for $\theta$ which is a normal distribution as
$$
f(\theta)  = \frac{1}{r\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\theta-\mu}{r\sigma}\right)^2}
$$
So the joint g-pdf would be
$$
f(x,\theta) = f(x|\theta)f(\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\frac{1}{r\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left[(\frac{x-\theta}{\sigma})^2 + (\frac{\theta-\mu}{r\sigma})^2\right]}
$$
By expanding the quadratic inside the exponent,
$$
(\frac{x-\theta}{\sigma})^2 + (\frac{\theta-\mu}{r\sigma})^2 = \frac{x^2 + \theta^2-2x\theta}{\sigma^2} + \frac{\theta^2 + \mu^2 - 2\theta\mu}{r^2\sigma^2}
$$

$$
=\frac{x^2r^2 + \theta^2r^2-2x\theta r^2 + \theta^2 + \mu^2 - 2\theta\mu }{r^2\sigma^2}
$$

$$
=\frac{\theta^2(1+r^2) - 2\theta(xr^2 + \mu) + (x^2r^2 + \mu^2)}{r^2\sigma^2}
$$

Now the marginal probability of $f(x)$ could be calculated from integration of joint probability of $f(x,\theta)$,
$$
f(x) = \int f(x,\theta)d \theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\frac{1}{r\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\int e^{\frac{-\theta^2(1+r^2) + 2\theta(xr^2 + \mu) - (x^2r^2 + \mu^2)}{2r^2\sigma^2}} d\theta 
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\frac{1}{r\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\frac{1+r^2}{2r^2\sigma^2}}}e^{\frac{(2\frac{(xr^2+\mu)}{2r^2\sigma^2})^2}{4\frac{1+r^2}{2r^2\sigma^2}}-\frac{x^2r^2+\mu^2}{2r^2\sigma^2}}
$$
We could simplify the terms inside the exponent as
$$
\frac{(xr^2+\mu)^2}{(2r^2\sigma^2)(1+r^2)}-\frac{x^2r^2+\mu^2}{2r^2\sigma^2} = \frac{(xr^2+\mu)^2-(x^2r^2+\mu^2)(1+r^2)}{(2r^2\sigma^2)(1+r^2)}
$$
$$
=\frac{x^2r^4+\mu^2+2xr^2\mu-x^2r^2-\mu^2-x^2r^4-r^2\mu^2}{(2r^2\sigma^2)(1+r^2)}
=\frac{2xr^2\mu-x^2r^2-r^2\mu^2}{(2r^2\sigma^2)(1+r^2)}
=\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{(2\sigma^2)(1+r^2)}
$$
Thus, the pdf of $f(x)$ will be
$$
f(x) =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2(1+r^2)}}e^{\frac{-1}{2}\left[\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{(\sigma^2)(1+r^2)}\right]}
$$